# iOS push notification is received without sound

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a hybrid application on mobilefirst platform 7 running on iphone/ipad.

everything goes well on push notification function except there is no sound played when apple devices received the push notification.

The same code works with sound for worklight 6.1, but seems mobilefirst platform 7 (build 20150729) cannot play the sound when push arrives.

Following is some sample code we used:

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, { alerts : alertCount });
var delay = WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription(notifyUser, notification);
```

Not sure if there are some fixpack existing for fixing this issue, or my code had missed something.

Comment: Is there something could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add to your payload:

```
sound: "default"
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html